# Visual Eevee bug

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I can not fix this issue when selecting EEVEE for my renders. It gets really annoying.

I can get rid of them temporary when I scroll out or into the viewport. Does anyone have an Idea how I can fix that? Blender version 2.81a

[image]

Comment: The problem appears with every project and even when I open Blender 2.8 :c

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It seems like a graphics driver issue, as in [this bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T67662). No idea how to fix it though, other than perhaps update drivers.

Comment: It llooks exactly like this issue, but my drivers are all updated. this problem makes me sad :c